# PowerShell - Loop through divs on webpage and print their ID

Tags: html, powershell

I'm using PowerShell to navigate to a webpage.  I'm looping through all the divs:

```
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application 

$ie.visible=$true

$ie.navigate("URL")   

$divs = $ie.document.getElementsByTagName("div")
Foreach($div in $divs)
{
    $div
}
```

This identifies the divs as being "System.__ComObjects".  Get-Member returns methods like "ie9_getAttribute" which sound promising (though I'm using IE11...) but "**$div.ie9_getAttribute("id")**" throws:

```
Exception calling "ie9_getAttribute" with "1" argument(s): "Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"
```

for the first div and:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] doesn't contain a method named 'ie9_getAttribute'.
```

for subsequent divs.

[Here is the HTML I am parsing.](http://pastebin.com/KRLv81v6)

How can I extract an ID from a "System.__ComObject"?

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to get the `.id` property of each object as you're iterating through the objects in `$divs`:

```
Foreach($div in $divs)
{
    $div.id
}
```